# Trying to pass data from UICollectionViewCell to UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

Trying to pass data from my `collectionViewCell` to another `UIViewController` but for some reason the data is not passed. Below is my code in `didSelectItem` method and the `ViewController` to which I want to pass the data. I am trying to populate label with the text passed over from my collection view cell data but it always shows the default string "test" that I have assigned in my `UIViewController`. Using swift 4.1

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let destinationVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CaseDetailViewController") as! CaseDetailViewController
        destinationVC.textPassedOver = MyCases[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }



// ViewController to pass data


class CaseDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var textPassedOver = "test"

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.text = textPassedOver

        print(textPassedOver)
       }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: check by printing MyCases[indexPath.section][indexPath.item] on did select whether u  r  receiving any value or not

Comment: also take     var textPassedOver : String?

Comment: @Dilip, Yes I did check and am receiving value in didselectitem at and i could it print it in console. The problem i have observed is the printstatement in viewdidload of CaseDetailViewController is executing first and then the statements in did select method are getting executeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out the solution. The work around was I deleted the didSelectItemAt and used didHighlightItemAt method instead. This way I could pass the data of the selected collectionviewCell to the viewcontroller. The reason I found that viewdidload method of uiviewcontroller is invoked only after didHighlightItemAt and before didSelectItemAt method.